# Erro 404 Not Found (nginx)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, http-status-404, fastcgi

Tenho um blog e de um dias para cá começou a dar o seguinte erro em algumas páginas.

```
           404 Not Found  nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)
```

O log de erro esta retornando:

```
           2016/02/02 10:44:12 [error] 612#0: *553172 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed 
           (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.x.xxx, server: 
           www.blogdeti.com.br , request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0",
           upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Minhas configurações do virtual host:

```
            server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on  default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.blogdeti.com.br;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&args;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root /var/www/html;
    }
           location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
 }
```

Minha hospedagem é a digital ocean e já tentei mandar um ticket de suporte, mas eles não conseguiram me ajudar.

Comment: Chegou a ver as configurações no `sites-enable`? parece que não esta encontrando a raiz do site

Comment: Sim, vou colocar as configurações do virtual host na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo o seu log e tenho a seguinte analise:

O arquivo ou o caminho para o mesmo está ...
Vamos analisar a tradução do erro

> > Vamos analisar a tradução do erro :::

```
02/02/2016 10:44:12 [erro] 612 # 0: * 553172 conectar () ao unix: /var/run/php5-fpm.sock falhou
   (11: Recurso temporariamente indisponível) durante a conexão com o upstream, cliente: xxx.xxx.x.xxx, servidor:
   www.blogdeti.com.br, solicitação: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP / 1.0",
   upstream: "fastcgi: // unix: /var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

A solução do problema é o seguinte...

Verificar a porta
E se os dados... O nome de servidor esta faltado
a versão sem WWW.

www é um redirecionamento diferente nas configurações DNS

Acessando

<<< http://www.
ou https://blogdeti.com
Isso é a parte de reditrecionamento. E isso se define um padrao. Quando configura o SSL.

Os mais populares LtsC como tambem CloudFlare

Ao contrario de um nome de host...
host.dominio.com